# A c program works well in Ubuntu but when I compile and run it in windows using MinGW, the program runs but in result it shows some garbage value

Tags: compiling, windows-10, c

I a wrote a C code in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and compiled it. It is working as expected.But in windows it is running but at last in result it is showing some garbage values.

The code I wrote is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct poly{
    int coe[100];
    };
void mul(struct poly *pr, int a, struct poly *p){
    struct poly res;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        res.coe[i] = 0;
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            res.coe[i] += ((*pr).coe[j])*((*(p + a)).coe[i - j]);
        }
    }
    *pr = res;

}
void main(){
    struct poly *p;
    p = (struct poly *)malloc(100*sizeof(struct poly));
    int n;
    printf("no. of poly :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i; int max = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int de;
        printf("deg? of %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &de); max += de;
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= de; j++){
            printf("co-eff of deg %d:", j);
            scanf("%d", &p[i].coe[j]);
        }
    }
    struct poly res;
    struct poly *pr;
    res = p[0];
    pr = &res;
    int fi;
    for(fi = 1; fi < n; fi++){
        mul(&res, fi, p);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < (max + 1); i++){
        printf("%d\n", res.coe[i]);
    }
}
```

and the result in windows is

```
C:\Users\Sai\Documents\C++>gcc ac.c -o ac

C:\Users\Sai\Documents\C++>ac
no. of poly :3
deg? of 1:2
co-eff of deg 0:1
co-eff of deg 1:1
co-eff of deg 2:1
deg? of 2:2
co-eff of deg 0:1
co-eff of deg 1:1
co-eff of deg 2:1
deg? of 3:2
co-eff of deg 0:1
co-eff of deg 1:1
co-eff of deg 2:1
1
3
6
85067032
255201082
510403447
-1897503563

C:\Users\Sai\Documents\C++>
```

the result in ubuntu is

```
sai@sai-Inspiron-7548:~$ gcc ac.c -o ac
sai@sai-Inspiron-7548:~$ ./ac
no. of poly :3
deg? of 1:2
co-eff of deg 0:1
co-eff of deg 1:1
co-eff of deg 2:1
deg? of 2:2
co-eff of deg 0:1
co-eff of deg 1:1
co-eff of deg 2:1
deg? of 3:2
co-eff of deg 0:1
co-eff of deg 1:1
co-eff of deg 2:1
1
3
6
7
6
3
1
sai@sai-Inspiron-7548:~$
```

How to make this program run correctly in windows 10.

Is something wrong in code that I wrote.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you would be better off with your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this should have been posted elsewhere, this is the solution:

**Always initialize!**

You are not initializing the `coe[100]` array of all the elements in your `struct poly*`.

In your loops you only set some of the entries, however your mul-function also accesses uninitialized ones.

I assume that gcc on linux somehow takes care of that by intilializing them as 0 by default, however the standard defines the value of an uninitialized integer as undefined.

MinGW does not intitialize it for you, so whatever is in the memory at that time messes up your results.

Edit: Of course you should also free the allocated memory with `free(p);`!

Here is how you can fix it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct poly{
    int coe[100];
};
void mul(struct poly *pr, int a, struct poly *p){
    struct poly res;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        res.coe[i] = 0;
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            res.coe[i] += ((*pr).coe[j])*((*(p + a)).coe[i - j]);
        }
    }
    *pr = res;

}
void main(){
    struct poly *p;
    p = (struct poly *)malloc(100*sizeof(struct poly));
    for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        for(int l = 0; l < 100; l++)
            p[k].coe[l] = 0;
    int n;
    printf("no. of poly :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i; int max = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int de;
        printf("deg? of %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &de); max += de;
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= de; j++){
            printf("co-eff of deg %d:", j);
            scanf("%d", &p[i].coe[j]);
        }
    }
    struct poly res;
    struct poly *pr;
    res = p[0];
    pr = &res;
    int fi;
    for(fi = 1; fi < n; fi++){
        mul(&res, fi, p);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < (max + 1); i++){
        printf("%d\n", res.coe[i]);
    }
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: Not to speak of the serious memory leak profided with this programm (*hint* malloc without freeing the resource later on)

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot to mention that. Added it to my answer.